# A-frame <a-video> autoplay

Tags: video, aframe

With A-Frame  I'm not able to get  autoplay="false" or loop="false" to work. The video plays automatically and loops anyway. I also tried the 'repeat' attribute from documentation, but that did not seem to work either: https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/primitives/a-video.html#attributes_repeat

How to get a video to not autoplay or loop in A-Frame?

```
<a-video position="0 3 -5" autoplay="false" loop="false"
         src="./assets2/video/Space-Cats-Magic-Fly.mp4"
         material="shader:flat; side:double; transparent:true;"
         geometry="mergeTo:null; primitive:circle; radius:3.0;">
</a-video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/#using-the-asset-management-system

Create a separate video element without autoplay/loop and reference it using an ID selector:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="vid" src="a.mp4"></video>
  </a-assets>

  <a-video src="#vid"></a-video>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: thank you.  makes sense to organize media this way in <a-assets> anyway.  
in this case, i want to dynamically change <a-video> source (with React) but can still pull it off by changing src in <a-assets>

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/machenmusik/pen/pRbJYj

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="myvideo" src="https://ucarecdn.com/bcece0a8-86ce-460e-856b-40dac4875f15/"></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#myvideo"></a-sky>
  <!-- or a-videosphere or a-video -->
</a-scene>
```

Comment: awesome.  i'll try this too

Answer (score 0):

Their is a turn-around way for this
Just pause the video at start and set the current time to 0.1

`const videoEl = document.querySelector('#vid');`
`videoEl.pause()`
`videoEl.currentTime = 0.1`